# Merge the rows of two arrays (appending row data from one array to a row in another array)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge, array-merge

I have two arrays populated from CodeIgniter query result sets (from calls of `result_array()`) and I need to merge the rows from the two arrays respectively/synchronously.

```
$array1 = [
    ['name' => 'John', 'course' => 'BSIT'], 
    ['name' => 'Jane', 'course' => 'BSHRM'],
];
$array2 = [
    ['balance' => '1000', 'date' => '2013-05-01'], 
    ['balance' => '2000', 'date' => '2013-05-07'], 
];
```

How can I append the elements `[balance], [date]` from `$array2` to `$array1` so that the result looks like this:

```
[
    [
        'name' => 'John',
        'course' => 'BSIT',
        'balance' => '1000',
        'date' => '2013-05-01'
    ], 
    [
        'name' => 'Jane',
        'course' => 'BSHRM',
        'balance' => '2000',
        'date' => '2013-05-07'
    ]
]
```

I have tried:

```
for($i = 0; $i<count($array1); $i++)
{
    array_merge($array1[$i], $array2[$i]);
}
```

but I get an error that `arguments are not array` even if I do it like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i<count($array1); $i++)
{
    array_merge(array($array1[$i]), array($array2[$i]));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the array_merge equal to something:

```
for($i = 0; $i<count($array1); $i++)
{
    $array1[$i] = array_merge($array1[$i], $array2[$i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$merged_array = array_map(function($a, $b) {
  return array_merge($a, $b);
}, $array1, $array2));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler way to merge the rows of two or more arrays.  Call `array_map()` with a callback of `array_merge()` and then list the arrays as final function parameters.  `array_map()` will synchronously isolate one row at a time from the input arrays so that `array_merge()` can combine the two rows into one.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/sEKl0))

```
var_export(
    array_map('array_merge', $array1, $array2)
);
```

Answer (score -1):

try using array_merge_recursive() function

Comment: This advice is [provably incorrect](https://3v4l.org/nLkas).